# Best regex (in Python) to not have double space in result when substring is removed?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove a substring using regex in Python.

The substring could be the entire string, at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end.

The goal is that the resulting string should not have extra spaces where the substring existed.

Could you suggest a simple and efficient regex that achieves this?

---

Here are examples of the scenarios*, and my expected results:

```
  'before remove after' --> 'before after' (separated by single space)
  'remove after'        --> 'after'        (no space)
  'before remove'       --> 'before'       (no space)
  'remove'              --> ''             (no space, empty string)
```

* `before`, `remove`, and `after` may themselves internally contain any character (letters, numbers, spaces, etc.).

---

The regex should achieve the following:

- If there was text before and text after the substring, the two parts should be separated by a single space.
- If there was only text before the substring, the result should not have a space at the end.
- If there was only text after the substring, the result should not have a space in the beginning.
- If there was no text before and no text after the substring, the result should be an empty string.

---

Here are a couple of my attempts, but I could not get all scenarios to work...

```
  import re

  s1 = 'before remove after'
  s2 = 'remove after'
  s3 = 'before remove'
  s4 = 'remove'

  # (1) Just replace with empty string ''...

  re.sub(r'remove', '', s1)
  'before  after'  # <-- bad (two spaces in result)

  re.sub(r'remove', '', s2)
  ' after'         # <-- bad (space in the beginning)

  re.sub(r'remove', '', s3)
  'before '        # <-- bad (space at the end)

  re.sub(r'remove', '', s4)
  ''               # <-- good (empty string)

  # (2) Capture the "before" part excluding space suffixes,
  #     capture the "after" part excluding space prefixes,
  #     and recombine them with a single space...

  re.sub(r'(.*?)\s*remove\s*(.*?)', '\\1 \\2', s1)
  'before after'   # <-- good (single space)

  re.sub(r'(.*?)\s*remove\s*(.*?)', '\\1 \\2', s2)
  ' after'         # <-- bad (space in the beginning)

  re.sub(r'(.*?)\s*remove\s*(.*?)', '\\1 \\2', s3)
  'before '        # <-- bad (space at the end)

  re.sub(r'(.*?)\s*remove\s*(.*?)', '\\1 \\2', s4)
  ' '              # <-- bad (should be an empty string)
```

Comment: What should be the output then there are multiple spaces like `before remove    after`?

Comment: Ideally I would have liked to see ''before after' (one space), 'after' (no spaces), 'before' (no spaces), and '' (no spaces) regardless of the number of spaces separating the parts of the initial string, but I wasn't clear enough on that point in my question. Your solution below does a really good job at that, except when the input is like '   remove   '. However, I really would like a "pure" regex solution that doesn't rely on lambda.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use a capturing group in the replacement instead of a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pattern without a lambda, you could use a capturing group in the replacement. That group should contain either a single space when remove is surrounded by words, or an empty string when only `remove` surrounded by optional spaces.

```
(?:(?<=\S)( )+)? *remove *(?(1) (?=\S)(?!remove\b))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?<=\S)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is a non whitespace char
  - `( )+` Capture **group 1**, repeat 1+ times matching a space which captures only the value of the last iteration that we need in the replacement
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `*remove *` Match `remove` between optional spaces
- `(?(1) (?=\S)(?!remove\b)` If clause, it group 1 exists, match a space asserting what is directly to the right is a non whitespace char but not the word `remove`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F9KlNn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1JSmni)

**Example code**

```
import re

strings = [
    'before remove after',
    'remove after',
    ' remove',
    'remove ',
    ' remove ',
    'before remove',
    'remove',
    'before   remove   after',
    'before remove     after remove before',
    'before remove after remove before remove',
    'before remove after remove before   remove   ',
    'after remove before before remove   remove remove',
    'remove remove    remove   '
]
pattern = r"(?:(?<=\S)( )+)? *remove *(?(1) (?=\S)(?!remove\b))"
for s in strings:
    print("'{0}' ==> '{1}'".format(s, re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s)))
```

**Output** (between single quotes to show the empty strings)

```
before remove after' ==> 'before after'
'remove after' ==> 'after'
' remove' ==> ''
'remove ' ==> ''
' remove ' ==> ''
'before remove' ==> 'before'
'remove' ==> ''
'before   remove   after' ==> 'before after'
'before remove     after remove before' ==> 'before after before'
'before remove after remove before remove' ==> 'before after before'
'before remove after remove before   remove   ' ==> 'before after before'
'after remove before before remove   remove remove' ==> 'after before before'
'remove remove    remove   ' ==> ''
```

**Note**

- If you want to match whitespace chars that could possibly also match a newline, you can use `\s` instead of a space.
- If you want to match whitespace chars without a newline instead of a space only, you can use `[^\S\r\n]`

Comment: The solutions suggested by Moritz and aziz k'h are efficient for simpler cases when there is a single space separating parts of the input sting. This solution covers a very wide range of inputs, as you can see from the list of strings above. This slightly more complex regex (`r"(?:(?<=\S)( )+)? *remove *(?(1) (?=\S)(?!remove\b))"` with `r"\1"` for replacement) works really well.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
import re

s ='before remove after'
s1 = 'remove after'    
s2 = 'before remove' 
s3 = 'remove'

print(re.sub(r"(remove\s?)|(\sremove)","",s))
print(re.sub(r"(remove\s?)|(\sremove)","",s1))
print(re.sub(r"(remove\s?)|(\sremove)","",s2))
print(re.sub(r"(remove\s?)|(\sremove)","",s3))
```

[demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Skv_if2sD)

Comment: Very simple and elegant. I'm trying to understand why it works?... Match on `remove` with zero or one space at the end; this will cover scenarios 1, 2, and 4. Otherwise, match on remove with one space in front; this will cover scenario 3. Did I interpret this correctly? Is there a reason to to use "?" instead of "+" ?

Comment: @PJSingh `(remove\s?)` only will cover 2 and 4. In the other hand  `(\sremove)`  will cover 1 and 3 and the secret of and this happened because re testing the string character by character and in the first case \s become before "r" character of "remove".
and why i use "?" instead of "+"  , as you know "+" mean 1 or more and "?" mean 0 or 1 i use "?" to cover 2 and 4 in same time else i would be used something like this `(remove\s)|(\sremove)|(remove)` , i hope this help you .

Comment: This is a good approach that works consistently when there are zero or one spaces in the input. Moritz's solution is similar but uses a `*` that handles additional spaces in scenarios 2 and 3. Both solutions work for the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the result you're looking for: `"remove\s*|\s*remove"`

```
import re
text_lst = ['before remove after', 'remove after', 'before remove', 'remove']
output_lst = []
for text in text_lst:
    output_lst.append(re.sub("remove\s*|\s*remove", "", text))
```

Comment: I think `remove\s*|\s*remove` will work as well, without the parenthesis. I can see why this works for scenarios 1, 2, and 4. Why does it also work for scenario 3 (`s3 = 'before remove'`)? In scenario 3, wouldn't the first part of the "or" (`remove(\s*)`) match first, giving us a result of "`before `" with a space at the end?

Comment: Yeah true, you can delete the parenthesis (was already removed in the code part). 
And good question about the third case. I don't 100% know why it works, but it does. Interestingly enough, when I switch it around and use  "\s*remove|remove\s*" I get an excess  space in front of " after" for scenario 2.

Comment: This is similar to the answer suggested by aziz k'h. Both are succinct and elegant. However, using `\s*` instead of `\s?`has the advantage of working for scenarios 2 and 3 when the input has extra spaces (such as `s2 = 'remove    after'` or `s3 = 'before    remove'`). Note that both solutions can't handle scenarios 1 and 4 with extra spaces very well (such as `s1 = 'before    remove    after'` or `s4 = '    remove    '`). Still, using `\s*` provides a little extra flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```py
import re

strs = ['before remove after','remove after','before remove','remove']
for s in strs:
    s = s.replace('remove','')
    s = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s).strip()
    print '"' + s + '"'
```

It outputs:

```
"before after"
"after"
"before"
""
```

Comment: This gets the job done, but I wonder if there is a single regex that can achieve both the `s.replace` and `re.sub` steps?

Comment: Check out @aziz k'h's answer, I think that's what you need.